# Recommendations for SIP-logfile viewer

Tags: software-recommendation, log, sip

I am searching for a viewer for SIP protocol logfiles.
I've stumbled about various tools, and would very much like to have a graphical display like this one:

- https://sipfoundry.atlassian.net/wiki/display/sipXecs/Display+SIP+message+flow+using+Sipviewer
- https://sipfoundry.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/491578/Sipviewer.png?version=1&modificationDate=1263129773000&api=v2

Only downside of that tool is that it requires java, which I am not allowed to install / use due to security concerns.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a SIP-logviewer that does not use or depend on java?

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on where your logfiles are coming from. There is no standard 'SIP Protocol logfile'.

If you need to trace SIP calls, my first recommendation would be [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). This is a network trace tool that can trace pretty much any IP protocol you can think of. It has a lot of SIP features, including producing the kind of ladder diagrams you want (Go to the Telephony->VOIP calls menu item). It can also play back audio.

It is available for most Operating Systems.

When debugging SIP calls it is worth realising that your problem may be at a different level - IP may be firewalled, the TCP (or UDP) socket may not be open, the DNS queries might not be working. All of these can be diagnosed from a Wireshark trace.

Wireshark can also read files saved by other programs, such as the Linux tcpdump program. I often take traces on SIP servers using tcpdump, and then debug them on my laptop.